# Structuring a document using comments

Tags: texmaker, texstudio

When I write in LaTeX, what I enjoy doing is to first write an outline and the proceedings of my argumentation, and then later filling that in with text.

Now, often, my argumentational structure has much smaller steps than I can highlight by actual outline (i.e. \section, \paragraph and alike). Therefore, I would like to be able to use comments in a way that my editor recognizes them as structuring elements; I would then be able to fold/unfold small blocks of text, only showing the comments which summarise this block.

I guess that this can be achieved by means of choosing the right editor. I am currently using Texmaker und Texstudio, but I am not fully convinced of either. Is there any tool that can do what I just described?

EDIT: Maybe I can further clarify my idea: I would wish for an editor to be able to interpret my comments and accordingly show this in the way it marks them in the editor-view. E.g. it might show certain comments in bold letters or in red font, but also fold and unfold blocks between certain comments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Texstudio you can use

```
% your comment here
%BEGIN_FOLD

whatever text

%END_FOLD
```

in order to fold a certain range of text.

To mark special comments in colour, a feature normally used for todo comments can be abused. If you add some phrase, for example `youroutline` to the list of recognised to-do comments, comments starting with this expression will be coloured (which colour/font colour/bold etc. is customisable):

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I set TODO-comments?

Comment: @Lukas In the "adv. Editor" tab of the texstudio preferences.

Comment: Is it possible to define other types of comments as well?

Comment: @Lukas ? What do you mean with types of comments?

Comment: like a todo-comment could be said to be a "type of" a comment.

Comment: @Lukas If I remember correctly, there had been a feature request to implement something like this, but currently there is only normal comment, (so called) magic comment and todo comments.

Comment: @samcarter, nice tip! I got curious, but didn't find here the option to add the todo regex (maybe my bad...). Which version of TeXStudio are you using?

Comment: @gusbrs I am using 2.12.6. Do you have "show advanced options" enabled?

Comment: @samcarter, that may be it, I'm stuck with the repo's 2.10.8... Yes, I do have "show advanced options" enabled, and I used the searchbox as well. I'll have to keep the trick for later on. Thanks!

Comment: @gusbrs or you don't use the one from your repos but a more recent version.

Comment: @Skillmon, I'm not sure I get your comment. But if it's an invitation to use vim, perhaps one day I'll get thus far.  ;-)

Comment: @gusbrs no I just meant you can use a recent version of TeXStudio which is not contained in your repositories. But if you want to start VIM, the earlier the better :)

Comment: @Skillmon, I got your comment only partially! (I suppose you edited it). I usually prefer to stick to the repos, but do get away from them when there's a good reason for it. My version is already lacking behind with the KOMA-Script sectioning commands (which are not recognized in the structure), perhaps it is indeed time for a manual installation. Or VIM, of course!  :)

Answer (score 7):

VIM.

Using `foldmethod=marker` and `foldmarker=>>>,<<<` you can fold everything in between `>>>` and `<<<`. If `TODO` is contained in a comment the `TODO` gets bold and in a highlighted colour. You could add more strings which are handled like `TODO` (but I'd have to look up how).

If you're really at it, you could as well define your own fold rules which handle your stuff without the additional markers.

Together with `vim-latexsuite` (a VIM plugin), you get other stuff to get your TeXing done faster.

Or you could look at the foldmethods provided by the `vim-latexsuite`.

Answer (score 5):

Most good editors support something like this.  For example in jEdit you can use a variety of custom folding commands, the most useful for (La)TeX being

```
%{{{ Some comment text if you want it
This is a block that I might want to fold up.
It might be quite long
%}}} some more comment text
```

which when folded would look like

```
%{{{ Some comment text if you want it
    [2 lines]
%}}} some more comment text
```